Cisco RV325 Router Disconnecting on Telus Fibre
Preface: Not a master of network configuration
I have had Telus Fibre for about 10 years.  For most of that time my configuration was from the Telus Supplied Modem (alcatel-lucent) connected to the WAN of my Cisco RV325 router.  Everything worked great until a few months ago.
I can still connect to the internet but at some point (maybe a couple minutes) all my connected devices start to fail to connect to the internet (still connected on LAN).  Their connection to the internet becomes intermittent (mostly not connected with the occasional brief connection).
If I connect the Telus supplied Router  (T3200M) I can connect to the internet through it with no problems.  If I configure the router to use "Port Bridging" and connect to my router's WAN I experience the same issues that I would if I connected directly to the modem - intermittent mostly unavailable.
I have updated the RV325 to the latest firmware and have factory reset it to no avail.  I have tried disconnecting all but a single device (computer on ethernet).
Currently, I have changed the RV325 to act like a switch (disabled DHCP) and use the Telus Router for DHCP - this isn't ideal as I don't get more advanced routing like VLANs etc.

Q1: Could there be something that Telus has changed on their network
that makes my router now incompatible?
Q2: Is there some setting in my RV325 that I could try so it might play nice with the Telus Network?
Q3: Is it possible that my
router has just failed (physically) for some reason (e.g. WAN circuits are
malfunctioning)?

One other thing I noticed - at some point I was no longer able to access my LAN remotely (via DDNS).  I used to be able to do this but I think Telus changed their network to use CGNAT (or similar) which seems to make it harder to connect from outside - my Telus Router IP is different than my reported IP - http://checkip.dyndns.org/ .  I'm not sure if the timing for this change was at about the same time.

If I read the details correctly in your question correctly you have two devices that are now 10 years old. Vague symptoms might be the result of the fact that they may simply be reaching the end of their lifespan. A replacement and/or upgrade of one or both might be required and/or sensible anyway since for example Cisco stopped offering software updates 6 years ago already https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/routers/rv320-dual-gigabit-wan-vpn-router/eos-eol-notice-c51-738763.html
